# Что попадает в переменную при пропуске строки

Tags: java, input

Если у меня есть условная переменная `int x`, в которую планировал положить значение пользователя, но пользователь пропустил ввод, то что будет в `х`?

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (true) {
        int id = scan.nextInt();
        //как провести проверку на "невведенность"?
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        if (name.isEmpty())
            break;
        map.put(name, id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: что помешало запусть код, "пропустить ввод" увидеть собственными глазами, что произойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каким образом "пропустил"? Если используем Scanner и пользователь нажимает enter, просто переведется строка. Сам сканнер будет ждать ввода до победного.

Comment: Я добавляю проверку, является ли введенное значение пустым и если да, то прекращаю ввод
Все значения складываются в мапу
Как мне проверять, пустой ли икс?
=="" ?

Comment: Он не может быть пустым, если мы используем nextInt(). Поток программы приостанавливается, пока не будет получен ввод. При использовании nextLine() - да, входная строка может быть пустой. Но тут у нас уже строка, а не int. Строку на пустоту можно проверить методом isEmpty(), дальше распарсить в целое число Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Если Вы добавили бы исходный код, который вызывает вопросы, было бы проще понять что у Вас вызывает трудности